# Which comes first View or View Model?

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm

When developing a MVVM WPF application is it better or more common to design the interface (View) first and then created the view model to bind to, or create the view model first?

Comment: Since there is a separation between the two, you can pick what you want to start with and it would have zero effect on the other. That said, I would start with the ViewModel.

Comment: Given that the view has to bind to the view model it would be best to start with the view model and go from there. You'll find that both will evolve as you develop your application.

Comment: i tend to develop both at the same time, but generally create the view model first.

Comment: I agree with gdoron. But personally, I prefer developing the View first just to make sure I took care of all the functional requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally start with the model classes, then kind of write the view model class with the view. By this I mean that I might declare some basic collection and selected item properties in the view model and knock up a basic data bound UI... I'm a fan of instant gratification. This is simply so that I have some data to use when designing the UI elements. I find that it makes sense to design the UI with data, so that I can see it as it will look when being used by the user straight away.

I then tend to add properties and functionality in sections, adding code into both the view and view model until the functionality has been implemented. Furthermore, I prefer to be able to hook up my data bound properties and `Command`s in the view and see them all working straight away, so for each section, I write the code in the view model before the view.

But I tend to work in terms of models, views and view models as one. I don't mean as one class, but I mean that if I need to display some people, then I have to define the model classes, the view *and* the view model before I can see any people. So for each type of view required, I define *all* of the necessary classes in the order stated above and then move onto the next set of models, view and view model.

But that's just how I prefer to do it. I think that if you just try writing the code in the different orders, then you'll soon find your own preference and for your own reasons.

By the way, this question is rather subjective, so don't be surprised if it gets deleted by the community because these kinds of questions don't really have one right answer.